# Why is $ u=\log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ not harmonic for $x^2 + y^2 <1$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, singularity

Since  $\displaystyle u = \frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)$  is, as already answered in this forum, harmonic for $\displaystyle x,y > 0$, and  $\Delta u = 0,$ i don't get why this function is not harmonic in $\displaystyle x=y=0$. Is there a condition for harmonic functions not to have singularities?

Comment: Simply because it is not defined  $(0,0)$

Comment: What does $\Delta u(0,0)=0$ mean when $u$ has a singularity at $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 0):

By definition harmonic functions are twice continuously differentiable everywhere on their domain. In particular that implies they are continuous so they can't have singularities.